# Debian 10 - add static route via alternate network link

Tags: debian, networking, route

I have a network `192.168.2.0/24` on which I have 2 computers, a desktop machine and a server.

The server has a VM running on it, which has the network address `192.168.122.0/24`.

The link between the desktop and the server is 100 Mb/s.

However there exists another link. It is a static link on the network `10.0.0.0/8`.

In other words, one end of the cable has ip `10.0.0.1` and the other end has `10.0.0.2`. This link is 1Gb/s.

Since the VM contains a file server, I would like to direct traffic to the ip address `192.168.122.0/24` via the static link.

I believe this can be done by adding a static route. But I do not know how to do it.

I tried to use the command

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.122.166/255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.2 dev enp6s0
```

however this produced an error which just displays the command usage. (Implying incorrect syntax.)

My system is Debian 10. Am I trying to do something sensible/possible and if so what am I doing wrong at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
route add -net 192.168.122.0/255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.2 dev enp6s0
```

Answer (score 0):

The right tool for add static routes for debian (and linux generaly) is [ip](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) command.

Run in terminal as root:

```bash
~] ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev enp6s0
```

But it is temporary solution. You must create permanent configuration. Here is [guide how add permanent static routes for debian systems](https://www.mybluelinux.com/debian-permanent-static-routes/).